# How to use sed and back references to print out substrings in unix?

Tags: unix, sed, terminal, backreference

Suppose I have the following file:

```
1.Walmart #U.S.A. 
2.SAP (Germany)
```

I want to erase everything from the file except for the number and the company name. Ex: No U.S.A. afterwards. But I am only allowed to use sed and backreferences. Nothing else

I tried something like:

```
sed -E 's/(U.S.A.), /s(Walmart)/\2, \1/g' file.txt
```

And the output should look like:

1.Walmart

2.SAP

Answer (score 2):

This removes the blank and everything after that.

```
sed 's/ .*//' file
```

Output:

```
1.Walmart
2.SAP
```

---

From `man sed`:

> `s/regexp/replacement/`:
>                 Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that portion matched  with
>                 replacement.

Comment: As i'm new to `sed`,Can you please explain the above command?

Comment: @User123: `s` is one of `sed`'s commands with uses [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Answer (score 1):

The backreference solution is

```
sed -E 's/(.*) (.*)/\1/g' file
```

But using back reference in such simple regex is just too much
You can do it as Cyrus suggested, or alternativelly:

```
$ grep -o '^[^ ]*' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the `s` command allows for exactly one regex and exactly one substitution.  You can perform multiple substitutions

```
s/[^A-Za-z0-9]*U\.S\.A\.[^A-Za-z0-9]*//
s/[^A-Za-z0-9]*Germany[^A-Za-z0-9]*//
```

or in this case, when the replacement is identical, combine them into a single regex:

```
s/[^A-Za-z0-9]*\(U\.S\.A\.\|Germany\)[^A-Za-z0-9]*//
```

If your `sed` supports `-E` you can remove the backslashes, but it's not portable, so I reverted to "traditional" `sed` regex syntax for this answer.

The `[^A-Za-z0-9]*` takes care of including any surrounding nonalphabetics (spaces, parentheses, punctuation, etc) in the match.

There is no reason to use a back reference for this, though of course, just to show you how it works, you can include everything before the country name and copy it back into the replacement:

```
sed 's/^\(.*[A-Za-z0-9]\)[^A-Za-z0-9]*\(U\.S\.A\.\|Germany\)[^A-Za-z0-9]*/\1/'
```

The `[A-Za-z0-9]` before the first closing parenthesis anchors the `.*` match so it doesn't grab any whitespace or punctuation before the country name.